# Prevent properties inheritance in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

I have several config files like:

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: default

application.someprop: common
```

**application-prod.yaml**

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: prod

application.someprop: prod
```

And I have a configuration class for this property with validation on it like:

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
public class ApplicationProps {
    @NotEmpty
    private String someprop;
}
```

So, the validation works fine when I delete **application.someprop** property from **application.yaml** config when I run the application with the default profile, but in case of running the app with **prod** profile **application-prod.yaml** and with removed **application.someprop** property,  value is inherited from the **application.yaml** and validation is not working.

The main use case of the absence of this property is a configuration mistake. So I need to show the appropriate and readable log to troubleshoot the problem.

I think I need some custom property spring **Binder.class** customization, but I could not find any solution for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What missing property?

Comment: *"when I delete this property"* What property is "this" referencing, i.e. what property are you talking about deleting? Please **edit** the question and clarify the wording.

Comment: @Andreas updated

Comment: `application.yaml` is *always* loaded, regardless of which profiles are active, so the `spring.profiles.active: prod` property in that file ensures that the `prod` profile is *always* active, which means that `application-prod.yaml` will *always* be loaded. Now that we've established that both files will *always* be loaded, if the `application.someprop` is defined in at least one of them, the property will have a value. Now, please **edit** the question and explain the conditions where you thing the property would not be defined.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the `spring.profiles.include` property in the previous comment, so I should have said that `prod` profile is always active *unless* overridden on the command-line. I read *"when I run the application with default profile"* to mean that you don't override the active profile, which is not that same as running with no active profile, where Spring will then make the `default` profile the active profile. Please clarify the question as to whether you mean the profile named "default", or are talking about general default behavior.

Comment: It's a feature of Spring boot that `application.yaml` is always loaded. If you don't like it, why are you using it?

Comment: @g00glen00b So the **Validated** annotation with all JSR-303 doesn't have any sense. I didn't see a project without the default `application.yaml`, also when using external config out of the jar properties are also inherited.

Comment: @cudouny If it's an environment-specific property, I would actually encourage you not to put it within the `application.yaml`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use different property values for different profiles, you need to give different values as follows. spring.profile.active does not define property for a specific profile, it only enables a profiles; and overrides any default properties if you have specified them explicitly. In case delete the property defined for a profile, it will always use the default one.

```
spring:
   profiles:
       active: prod
application.someprop: prop-default-value

---

spring:
   profiles: prod
application.someprop: prop-prod-value

---

spring:
   profiles: dev
application.someprop: prop-dev-value
```